# incomplete visualization of footprints of buildings - osmnx package (example of gboeing nº 10)

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm studying the OSMNX package following the examples available in Geoff Boeing's git ([enter link description here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/tree/master/notebooks)) and I'm learning a lot.
However, in example 10 (building footprints), I have a problem (I do not have the output of the footprints, as seen in the image below).

[image]

The codes generate the street networks of the requested urban spaces, but do not generate the footprints (as it should be, as the image below highlighted in orange).

[image]

Ps. I'm not changing the codes available in github, just giving "Kernel-restart & clearOutput" to refactor them as I read them.

Ps. As in this case, it does not return an error (returns street views, but not the footprints of the overlapping buildings) I could not find the solution when I gave google.

```
import osmnx as ox
from IPython.display import Image
%matplotlib inline
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = "C:/Users/My/Anaconda3/Library/share"

img_folder = 'images'
extension = 'png'
size = 240

gdf = ox.buildings_from_place(place='Piedmont, California, USA')
gdf_proj = ox.project_gdf(gdf)
fig, ax = ox.plot_buildings(gdf_proj, bgcolor='#333333', color='w', 
                        save=True, show=False, close=True, filename='piedmont_bldgs', dpi=40)
Image('{}/{}.{}'.format(img_folder, 'piedmont_bldgs', extension), height=size, width=size)
gdf_save = gdf.drop(labels='nodes', axis=1)
gdf_save.to_file('data/piedmont_bldgs')
areas = gdf_proj.area
areas.head()
sum(areas)
place = ox.gdf_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA')
place_proj = ox.project_gdf(place)
place_proj.area.iloc[0]
sum(areas) / place_proj.area.iloc[0]

point = (48.873446, 2.294255)
dist = 612
gdf = ox.buildings_from_point(point=point, distance=dist)
gdf_proj = ox.project_gdf(gdf)
bbox = ox.bbox_from_point(point=point, distance=dist, project_utm=True)
fig, ax = ox.plot_buildings(gdf_proj, bgcolor='#333333', color='w', figsize=(4,4), bbox=bbox,
                        save=True, show=False, close=True, filename='paris_bldgs', dpi=90)
Image('{}/{}.{}'.format(img_folder, 'paris_bldgs', extension), height=size, width=size)

# until that moment everything happened according to the tutorial

def make_plot(place, point, network_type='drive', bldg_color='orange', dpi=40,
          dist=805, default_width=4, street_widths=None):
gdf = ox.buildings_from_point(point=point, distance=dist)
gdf_proj = ox.project_gdf(gdf)
fig, ax = ox.plot_figure_ground(point=point, dist=dist, network_type=network_type, default_width=default_width,
                                street_widths=street_widths, save=False, show=False, close=True)
fig, ax = ox.plot_buildings(gdf_proj, fig=fig, ax=ax, color=bldg_color, set_bounds=False,
                            save=True, show=False, close=True, filename=place, dpi=dpi)

place = 'portland_buildings'
point = (45.517309, -122.682138)
make_plot(place, point)
Image('{}/{}.{}'.format(img_folder, place, extension), height=size, width=size)
# here is the problem
```

I get as output only the network of streets, without the footprint of the buildings (as shown in the first image above).

Info:

```
Conda version: 4.6.8

version conda-build: 3.17.8

python version: 3.6.7.final.0

platform: win-64

user-agent: conda / 4.6.8 requests / 2.21.0 CPython / 3.6.7 Windows / 10 Windows / 10.0.17134

nx .__ version__ = '0.9'
```

I would be happy if you could help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're projecting the footprints but not the street network so they don't align in the plot. Don't project the footprints, and it should work fine.

The example on GitHub needs to be updated as it dates back to an earlier version of OSMnx that automatically projected the street network figure-ground diagram.

Answer (score 0):

It is working when you do not use project_gdf as the first param in the plot_buildings funtion. Furthermore i am using the footprints module instead of the deprecated once.

```
def make_plot(place, point, network_type='drive', bldg_color='orange', dpi=dpi,
          dist=805, default_width=4, street_widths=None):
gdf = ox.footprints.footprints_from_point(point=point, distance=dist)
fig, ax = ox.plot_figure_ground(point=point, dist=dist, network_type=network_type, default_width=default_width, street_widths=street_widths, save=False, show=False, close=True)
fig, ax = ox.footprints.plot_footprints(gdf, fig=fig, ax=ax, color=bldg_color, set_bounds=False, save=True, show=False, close=True, filename=place, dpi=dpi)
```

edit: just open a pull request with this improvement: [enter link description here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/pull/20)